# How to edit SharePoint 2010 function variables

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I want to ask how to edit SharePoint 2010 function ? From source code I can see a function that is automatically generated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function _initTRAWebPartWPQ3()
{var toolbarData = new Object();toolbarData['ToolbarData'] = .....;
toolbarData['CurrentUserInfo']=[{id:'172',loginName....;
}
```

Is it possible by adding javascript to page to edit toolbarData object ? For example:

```
function _initTRAWebPartWPQ3(x){
    toolbarData['CurrentUserInfo'] = x;
    };

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(_initTRAWebPartWPQ3('Stewe'), "sp.ribbon.js");
```